# Very basic manipulation of numpy in python functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was always thinking to avoid loop operation in my python code. Numpy really helps, but in some slightly complicated cases, I felt stuck on how to utilize numpy array wisely.

Below is an simple example illustrating my inability, a will be a parameter, and b is an numpy array.

```
def f(a,b):
    return np.sum( a * b)
```

so there is no problem if I wish to evaluate this function by a given single parameter and an array.

```
x = 2
y = np.arange(3)
print (f(x,y))
```

But sometimes I want to evaluate different parameter value of the function altogether with a fixed array value.

I would try:

```
x2 = np.array([1,4,5,2,8])
print (f(x2,y))
```

What I wish to get is surely an array with value:

```
[f(1,y),f(4,y),f(5,y),f(2,y),f(8,y)]
```

However, python will try to evaluate the dot product of x and y, since now they are both np arrays and It will report

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,)
```

How should I overcome this, in numpy array-wise fashion, producing the sequence

```
[f(1,y),f(4,y),f(5,y),f(2,y),f(8,y)]
```

without using loops?

(In this example, I could resolved problem by modify f by:

```
def f(a,b):
    return a * np.sum(b)
```

But in most general cases, we cannot factor the parameter out.)

Comment: in [f(1,y),f(4,y),f(5,y),f(2,y),f(8,y)] y would be an array of length 3. So what numbers would you expect to appear? Should this become a 3x5 array?

Comment: For the summation calculation, you can just do - `x2*y.sum()`.

Comment: To @FabianRost, I am expecting to get 1x5 array, the i'th entry gives the value of f(x2[i],y)

Comment: @Divakar, I understand this way work, because we can factor the x out of the summation. In general, x and y is not separable before taking summation. For instance  if f(a,b) =  np.sum (sin( a * b)).

Comment: @LienongXu In that case do - `(np.sin(y[:,None]*x2)).sum(0)`. As long there is a `ufunc` for it, its doable that way.

Comment: @Divakar, this is the most handy way so far. I will try to generalize to arbitrary function. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`np.newaxis` is a very handy tool for cases like this, and gives you a bit more control over broadcasting. In this case, you'll want to add a new axes to give numpy some hints about where to broadcast:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,4,5,2,8])
>>> y = np.arange(3)
>>> x[:,np.newaxis] * y
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 0,  5, 10],
       [ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 0,  8, 16]])
```

If you'd like the sums along the second axis, you can sum like this:

```
>>> (x[:, np.newaxis] * y).sum(axis=1)
array([ 3, 12, 15,  6, 24])
```

Comment: `np.newaxis` is redundant in `y[np.newaxis,:]`.

Comment: Also, I think OP is summing elements along the second axis for the desired output.

Comment: Thanks - didn't see all of the comments on the question.

Comment: @pnhgiol, I will take it. Valuable answer.

Comment: `numpy` might not require `y[np.newaxis, :]`, but dumb humans might find it clearer.  I could even omit the ':', and use `y[None]` (but that would not add clarity).